# tramp runs on odt export --

Tags: org-export, tramp, odt

this is slightly embarrassing, but i'm confused about it so:

i run emacs 26.1, org 9.3.

when i use the org exporter to export a file to odt format, tramp fires up and runs on the newly created file. after the .odt is created, in *messages* i get a message like, `"Tramp: Opening connection for file /path/to/new/file.odt"` and i have a buffer (and tramp process?) named `*tramp/archive file /path/to/new/file.odt*`. the new odt file is 'mounted'. when i exit emacs, it first has to 'unmount' the file. it also shows up as a mounted 'drive' in my file manager. i find this very bizarre.

the only things in my init file about tramp are:

- tramp-backup-directory-alist (set to a file path)
- tramp-default-method (set to "ssh")
- tramp-mode-hook auto-sudoedit

my only org-export conf in my init it:

- require 'ox
- require 'ox extra
- ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines)

*

if this is too weird to help me troubleshoot: is there a way to just block/disable tramp? i very rarely use it, and use the odt exporter much more often.

Comment: ``M-x customize``, ``tramp``, ``Tramp mode``, toggle to ```off``` disables it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hit by the new tramp-archive.el package, which regards *.odt files as an archive (like *.tar files). In order to disable this, you might add the following to your ~/.emacs:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tramp-archive
  (setq tramp-archive-enabled nil))
```

However, there might be an error in the org exporter, because tramp-archive is activated only for a file name xxx.odt/ (note the trailing slash). Maybe you report this to the org people.

Comment: thanks for this. disabling it does work. but then i'm still wondering, what other functionality am i disabling?

Comment: Tramp file archives. Since you don't use them, you might not miss them :-) Tramp itself shall still be enabled.