# tramp -- open shell prompt for existing connection

Tags: tramp, shell

i started using the eldritch and mysterious tramp again because a user on here helped me fix it. (thanks michael: [tramp runs on odt export --](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56332/tramp-runs-on-odt-export/56345?noredirect=1#comment88375_56345)).

i create org mode links to my commonly-used remote conf files. when i click on them my tramp session starts up successfully.

it's possibly a no-brainer, but my question is how can i drop to a shell after i'm done finishing editing my conf file? to like restart a service or similar.

i know i can run `shell` or `eshell` and run ssh, but that starts a new connection which is really no different to reaching for the terminal emulator. surely i can magically just shell within my existing tramp connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x shell` runs always a new shell asynchronously, which means a new connection. If you just need to run a command on the remote host, consider `shell-command`. Something like `(shell-command "hostname")` is an example for this.

Answer (score 2):

Invoking `M-x shell` from a buffer with a remote file name should start a shell on the remote host.

The same thing applies to most commands which start a process.

> how can i drop to a shell after i'm done finishing editing my conf file?

It sounds like you simply need to use `M-x shell` in that conf file's buffer.